# SQL to JSON - How to get query output without column names then put together the two columns

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

For example, a table called User has columns FirstName and LastName. So when I query

```
SELECT * FROM User FOR JSON PATH
```

The output is

```
[{ "FirstName": "Bruce",
   "LastName": "Wayne"
}]
```

But the output I am trying to get is

```
[{ "Bruce" : "Wayne" }]
```

Comment: This is pretty simple output. You can just concatenate the values and build the string.

Answer (score 4):

In JSON, the structure is `"Property" : "Value"`. You are attempting to create a JSON with the structure `"Value" : "Value"`.
I'm not sure why you would want such a thing or even if it's a good idea, but to get to this you can create the output string yourself as gotqn suggested in his comment instead of using `FOR JSON`.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE [user]
(
    FirstName varchar(10),
    LastName varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO [User] (FirstName, LastName) VALUES 
('Bruce', 'Wayne'),
('Clark', 'Kent'),
('Peter', 'Parker'),
('Tony', 'Stark')
```

The query:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (
    SELECT ',{"'+ FirstName +'" : "'+ LastName +'"}' 
    FROM [User]
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
, 1, 1, '[') + ']' As JsonOutput
```

Results:

```
JsonOutput
[{"Bruce" : "Wayne"},{"Clark" : "Kent"},{"Peter" : "Parker"},{"Tony" : "Stark"}]
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (
    SELECT ',"'+ cast( ColumnName AS nvarchar) +'" : "'+ cast(ColumnName AS nvarchar) +'"' 
    FROM Site_Culture
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
, 1, 1,'')  As JsonOutput
```