# embed subquery result as csv inside another as json in mssql

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-data-studio

I must provide query results in json format, one of the data strings is an array/list. I can provide the query and get a result but the system ingesting it requires it in a slightly different format, can anyone help with my query to achieve this.

We are querying a publications database, two tables, [publications] and a table linking them to user accounts [publications-users] a single result is shown below:

```
{
    "_publication": {
        "identifier": "a2v3h2t8e7w",
        "authors": "Smith M; Jones G; Atkinson R",
        "title": "A publication about something.",
        "researchers": [
            {
                "uid": "user658"
            },
            {
                "uid": "user663"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

using code something like:

```
SELECT P.[id] as '_publication.identifier',
  P.[authors] as '_publication.authors',
  P.[title] as '_publication.title',
  ( SELECT PU.[userid] FROM [publications-users] PU WHERE P.[id]=PU.[pubid] FOR JSON PATH) as '_publication.researchers'
FROM [publications] P
FOR JSON PATH;
```

but the software receiving the json requires the researchers bit to  be formatted as a CSV string:

```
{
    "_publication": {
        "identifier": "a2v3h2t8e7w",
        "authors": "Smith M; Jones G; Atkinson R",
        "title": "A publication about something.",
        "researchers": [
            {
                "user658","user663"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I found STRING_AGG but this not available in Azure Data Studio

> 'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Suggestions for best way to achieve this output please? It's probably really simple, I just can't get it!

Comment: Function has nothing to do with Azure Data Studio, what version of SQL Server are you running (`SELECT @@VERSION;` not About ADS)? How _exactly_ are you referencing `STRING_AGG()`?

Comment: Good point ... it's Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3) so STRING_AGG not available. I can't upgrade this, not my server, is there another way?

Comment: Can you show the source tables and a few rows of sample data? Maybe a [fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle)?

Comment: have done this as a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=40443ea3617e574f85be31a4b13a1118

Comment: I'm not sure if the exact output you want (`"researchers":[{850,853,856}]`) is possible using native `FOR JSON` methods. [I come pretty close here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e5d567e38df52f44bca33f49cb3017b9) by nesting `FOR JSON PATH` to get `"researchers":[{"MeaninglessAlias":"850,853,856"}]`, but I don't know how to get rid of the meaningless alias _or_ eliminate quotes around the string. You may need to explore more elaborate ways, e.g. [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53576089/61305).